# Produce keyboard Events key hits

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-8.10

How to make a simple C program which will produce keyboard key hits.

```
if ( condition ) {
    KeyPress('A');
}
```

I am working on Ubuntu 8.10 Linux OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Get Fake Key Events by Xdotool**

```
//Compile As:  gcc button.c -lX11 

#include < X11/Xlib.h >
#include < X11/Xutil.h >
#include < stdio.h >
#include < X11/extensions/XTest.h >

void press_button()
{   
    Display *d;
    d = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        if(d == NULL)
        {
            //fprintf(stderr, "Errore nell'apertura del Display !!!\n");
            //exit(0);
        }
    system("xdotool key Shift+a");
    XFlush(d);
    XCloseDisplay(d);
}

int main() {
    press_button();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Here's a simple example using libxdo (from xdotool). (Caveat: I am the xdotool author)

```
 /* File: testkey.c
 *
 * Compile with:
 * gcc -lxdo testkey.c
 *
 * Requires libxdo (from xdotool project)
 */

#include <xdo.h>

int main() {
  xdo_t *xdo = xdo_new(NULL);
  xdo_keysequence(xdo, CURRENTWINDOW, "A", 0);
  return  0;
}
```

Comment: It seems `xdo_keysequence` has been renamed to `xdo_send_keysequence_window`; in Ubuntu 14.04 at least. By the way, should I call `xdo_free` afterwards? libxdo is very nice by the way, I'd suggest a one-page tutorial for it - it took me an hour to get here; trawling through xdotool code, I had no idea I could get away without a `context`.

Answer (score 2):

There is `XTestFakeKeyEvent()` function from Xlib.

[You can  USE Expect for c or C++ Programs](http://npg.dl.ac.uk/MIDAS/manual/ActiveTcl8.4.9.0-html/expect/libexpect.3.html)

Comment: is there any other way NOT using X11

Comment: go for Expect is one for i am using for same operation

Comment: Thanks ! Will you please provide me how to use Expect, as its really new for me . 
Regards.

Comment: can you provide me XTestFakeKeyEvent(). I compile my c program i get an error of

button.c:(.text+0x9d): undefined reference to `XTestFakeKeyEvent'

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [xsendkey](http://people.csail.mit.edu/adonovan/hacks/xsendkey.html). The sources are included and are short, so you extract the necessary parts from it into your program.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not C, you can produce key hits in Java very easily:

```
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class key
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.delay(2000);
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Swinput](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/swinput).

> Swinput can fake a mouse and a
>   keyboard by using the Linux Input
>   System. The swinput modules read from
>   a device and fakes hardware event
>   (mouse motion, key presses etc) as
>   commands written on the devices.

Comment: Thanks ! It seems Swinput works  with kernel space. I am looking for some user space application