# Send keystroke to not focused display

Tags: c++, linux, qt, x11, keyevent

I'm trying to send key events to a display event if it is not in the foreground.

At the moment i'm doing the following:

```
Display *d_;
d_ = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
system(QString("xdotool key Shift+F8").toStdString().c_str());
XFlush(d_);
XCloseDisplay(d_);
```

Though this is not working when the display is not focused.

So my questions are:

1. How can I send the key event to the display when it's not
   focused.
2. Is there a nicer way for sending a keystroke than
   starting a tool via shell?
3. Why do I have to open a new Display
   before using the shell command?

I'm using Qt and the code should run on Linux.

Comment: Do you have control over the foreground display when the target display is in the background??

Comment: for q2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108926/produce-keyboard-events-key-hits

Comment: I actually don't knwo if I have control. What do I need to do for having it?
The display is focused on startup, so basically my code is operating with that display. I don't have any PIDs though.

Comment: sure: system("xdotool key Shift+F8");   :-)

Comment: This means xdotool must be installed on the executing machine :-), I'm looking for a function which is on any X machine.

Comment: Did you consider to use XGrabKey to register hot keys? Or what you need is not hot key?

Comment: I don't think XGrabKey will help me here. XGrabKey is for fetching results, not for sending, right?